# PHP Notice: Use of undefined constant rootMP3URL - assumed rootMP3URL

Tags: php, notice

I keep getting this error message PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant rootMP3URL - assumed rootMP3URL

```
 // Remove the PHP script name from the URL.
        if ($stripScriptName) {
                //$rootMP3URL =  substr($rootMP3URL, 0, strrpos ($rootMP3URL, "/")); // Trim off script name itself
                $webFolder = dirname($webFolder);
                $options['$rootMP3URL'] = dirname('rootMP3URL');
                $debugger->debug("dirname({$options['$rootMP3URL']}) = " . dirname('rootMP3URL'));
                $debugger->debug("dirname($webFolder) = " . dirname($webFolder));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes about when you use a un-quoted string for an array index ($arr[rootMP3URL]), but I don't see that in your code. However, it is using `$rootMP3URL` as a string instead of evaluating it as a variable. You can either use double-quotes:

```
$options["$rootMP3URL"] = dirname('rootMP3URL');
$debugger->debug("dirname({$options["$rootMP3URL"]}) = " . dirname('rootMP3URL'));
```

or none at all

```
$options[$rootMP3URL] = dirname('rootMP3URL');
$debugger->debug("dirname({$options[$rootMP3URL]}) = " . dirname('rootMP3URL'));
```